# Safari 8 Not Clearing Redirect Data

Tags: safari, macos, browser-history

So this is a bit complex of a question. I have a domain, and I recently switched it from one host to another. Unfortunately, Safari doesn't realize that, and instead of loading the new server with data on it, it loads the default error page of the old one. It's not a hosting issue -- other browsers are working fine even on my computer.

So the question is this: where does Safari store this data, and how can I destroy it?

Edit: I have cleared Website Data in Preferences, History and Website Data in the Safari menu and Caches in the Develop menu.

Comment: I was in the same situation you were just a couple days ago, though clearing the caches through Develop > Empty Caches worked for me when you stated explicitly in your question you tried it and it failed to yield results. Odd.

Comment: @MichaelCooke: Develop > Empty Caches worked for me just now. See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227662/how-do-i-fully-flush-cached-redirects-from-safari

Answer (score 1):

A posible solution is to Reset DNS Cache.

You can do it with `dscacheutil -flushcache`. For more info type `man dscacheutil` on the terminal.