# localhost redirecting to https after Mojave upgrade

Tags: safari, security, mojave

After the recent upgrade to macOS Mojave Safari started redirecting from `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`. The problem persists only in Safari, in Chrome everything is the same as before. Now I'm temporary using `127.0.0.1` as a replacement, but it's inconvenient due to some limitations of software I'm using.

I tried searching and found some similar questions, where accepted answers were to kill Safari and remove `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist` file, and in my case it didn't work.

I also tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227662/how-do-i-fully-flush-cached-redirects-from-safari), without luck.

Comment: is it the SIP on Mojave doing it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃, I disabled SIP in order to remove `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari did that before Mojave.

Try this to fix it

```
sudo killall nsurlstoraged
rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist
launchctl start /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist
```

Comment: That helped, thanks! Actually, I was wondering if anything could be done with SIP enabled, as it was in the question my is marked as a possible duplicate of, because I wasn't able to remove HSTS file with SIP enabled.